# Execution time for sql files - batch operation

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a bunch of SQL queries stored as files on disk.
They are all pure `SELECT` queries or in other words, they only do read operations.

I am connecting to Oracle 11g database and I want to measure approximate execution time of all these queries. Is there any way to do this programmatically?

The database is on a server which is behind a firewall and as such I can connect to database only through Toad or Oracle SQL developer. So, writing my own java/python code is not an option here.

Comment: If you can connect with SQL Developer & Toad, you can connect with anything else.

Comment: Depending on how you run the files, can't you just `set timing on` in the SQL Developer worksheet?

Comment: @Mat: Not exactly in my case. Toad and SQL developer are on a machine which is inside the firewall and I remote into it. But, I don't have access to command prompt, task manager and a whole bunch of things on this intermediate machine.

Comment: cheap trick: print sysdate before and after :) If it doesn't then run your scripts through a cron or a scheudler which would give you a value for total run time

Comment: @realspirituals: Can you describe a little more?

Comment: how you launch your SQL files

Comment: I don't exactly launch them. I open them, copy paste query and execute the query. I know its sluggish but I don't know any other way at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of a couple of options while using TOAD.

**Option 1:** This should work in TOAD by pressing <kbd>**F5**</kbd>

```
TURN SPOOL ON -- Spool the results
SET TERMOUT OFF -- Controls the display of output generated by commands executed from a script.
SELECT * FROM TABLE;
SPOOL OFF
```

**Option 2:** This should work in TOAD by pressing <kbd>**F5**</kbd> But this will not print the results of the query.

```
SET AUTOTRACE TRACEONLY
YOUR QUERY
```

**Option 3:** This should work in TOAD by pressing <kbd>**F5**</kbd>

```
SET TIMING ON -- Controls the display of timing statistics.
YOUR QUERY
```

**Eg for option 3**

```
SET TIMING ON
SELECT bla FROM bla...
...
Elapsed: 00:00:00:01
SELECT bar FROM foo...
...
Elapsed: 00:00:23:41
SET TIMING OFF
```

To run all scripts and find overall time

```
TIMING START allmyscripts
... run all my scripts ...
TIMING STOP
timinig for: allmyscripts
Elapsed: 00:00:08.32
```

A DBA style find using the following columns in V$SQL

```
APPLICATION_WAIT_TIME
CONCURRENCY_WAIT_TIME
CLUSTER_WAIT_TIME
USER_IO_WAIT_TIME
PLSQL_EXEC_TIME
CPU_TIME
ELAPSED_TIME
```

**Note:** I suggest Option 3

Comment: Always turn off Database_Output, because writing outputs to the screen is sloooooooowwwww - and you will get tricked by optimizations of TOAD and SQLDev, as they only fetch the first few rows of a query until you scroll down - with autotrace only, you get the time the DB needs

Comment: select and return time will be lesser than retrieving all rows since it is the actual write time. So it depends on the user to decide

Comment: @Falco: How do I turn off output display? I am using SQL*Plus from Oracle SQL Developer with `set autotrace traceonly exp stat` and it tells me that traceonly is not currently supported..

Comment: @tumchaaditya I just tested it with SQL*Plus and "set autotrace traceonly" works just as described... Maybe you SQLPlus or DB Version is too old - or it is a configuration setting on your Database or on your User ?

Comment: @realspirituals what do you mean? Even with output off, SQL*Plus will still receive all rows via network - just look at the trace, the only thing not happening is printing to console, which is slow and never done in a real application, since noone will read 10Million rows on the console...

Comment: @Falco What I mean is that traceonly and actual spool will have different timings

Comment: Of course... but I don't know any real world application, where the users will work on the console to view huge masses of data ^_^ so spooling is usually off and the data is sent via network to a client application, which will provide some sort of presentation, which has completely different performance impact than the SQL*Plus console and shopuld thus be benchmarked separately.

Comment: I do know some real world massive reportings :) which is a pain point that cant be ignored

Answer (score 2):

I would perform an insert into a logging table before the select and update it after each select.

This will allow you not only to query today's time, but also to query the history, and detect or backtrace increase increase of the execution time.

Table could be related to a small web application to show you data and tends in a graphical manner, to keep your boss happy :D

```
create table batch_log (
batch_name varchar2(100) not null,
run_id varchar2(100) not null,
start_time date not null,
stop_time date not null);

insert into batch_log ('myFisrtSelect',date(sysdate), sysdate, sysdate);

select ....

update batch_log set stop_time=sysdate where batch_name='myFisrtSelect' and run_id=date(sysdate):
```

Of course, the run_id could be something better than just the day (especially if run just before midnight).

Table could be reused for other batch jobs performing inserts, update, etc... to log additional info (number of rows treated, affected,etc..).

Insert/update could also be centralized in a procedure (inside a package?).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the blunt way, set all the selects in 1 file, add dbms outputs with the timestamps in milliseconds (or just add some variables to do that). Or like somebody else said, add timestamps to a log table.